# Adding node labels to dendrogram plot in dendextend

Tags: r, dendextend

I have a dendrogram with leaf and node labels (class=phylo, read in using read.tree). After converting this to dendrogram class the node labels are not there anymore. However, I would like to plot the dendrogram by showing labels on top of some nodes (i.e in the form NODE_1 etc. on top of the selected clusters).

Does anyone know how can I get node labels to dendrogram class and add them to the plot?
Something similar like this, but instead of numbers there are id-s or labels and only some selection of nodes have the labels.

[image]

Comment: You could use `get_nodes_xy` but I'm not sure how to manage the logic of how to store and tell each node what to plot.

Answer (score 0):

I would convert your dendrogram to `phylo` class with `as.phylo`. When plotting you can do `plot(phylo, show.node.label = TRUE)`.

Comment: Thank You for the suggestion, but it seems that plotting as phylo doesn't show the scales, not so easy to plot horizontally and also I'm not sure that I can use color_branches() with this class.

Comment: @Liis Kolberg You can color your phylo branches with `edge.color` and set the colors you want. With the function `add.scale.bar` you can plot your scale.